# Raku/Perl6: how do you code a NULL with NativeCall

Tags: raku, nativecall

https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall

```
 "As you may have predicted by now, a NULL pointer
 is represented by the type object of the struct type."
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexw

```
 C++
 LSTATUS RegQueryValueExW(
   HKEY    hKey,
   LPCWSTR lpValueName,
   LPDWORD lpReserved,
   LPDWORD lpType,
   LPBYTE  lpData,
   LPDWORD lpcbData
 );

 lpReserved
 This parameter is reserved and must be NULL.
```

With "native", how do I satisfy the "NULL" requirement?

```
constant WCHAR   := uint16;
constant DWORD   := int32;

sub RegQueryValueExW( DWORD, WCHARS, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD is rw, DWORD is rw ) is native("Kernel32.dll") returns DWORD { * };

$RtnCode = RegQueryValueExW( $Handle, $lpValueName, int32, REG_DWORD, $lpData, $lpcbData );
```

"int32" returns:

> ```
> Cannot unbox a type object (int32) to int in method
> CALL-ME at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\sources \947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F9
> 23A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 587
> ```

Many thanks,
-T

Comment: Can you try pass an explicit 0 instead of the type `int32`?

Comment: passing it a zero does not work

Comment: Ok, I think I understand: `lpReserved` is a `DWORD *` not just a `DWORD`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's at best a typo, at worst an unspecified "booboo". The first comment ("Can you try pass an explicit `0`?") nailed the solution, but Todd replied "passing it a zero does not work" before posting and accepting his own answer that says "just pass it a zero. I had a booboo". Imo there should be an instant signal that reading this is likely to be a waste of readers' time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JJ and Brad on the Perl6 mailing list were correct.  For a NULL, just pass it a zero.  I had a booboo somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

To pass a pointer to a `DWORD` you can use a `CArray[DWORD]`. For example, here I created a test library `libmylib.so` with a `foo()` function taking `DWORD *` (aka `int32_t *`) argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void foo (int32_t *bar) {
    if ( bar == NULL ) {
        printf( "Got NULL pointer\n" ); 
    }
    else {
        printf("Got bar: %d\n", bar[0]);
    }
}
```

Then test a Raku interface to this library using:

```
use v6;
use NativeCall;

constant DWORD := int32;
sub foo(CArray[DWORD]) is native("./libmylib.so") { * };
my @bar := CArray[DWORD].new;
@bar[0]  = 1;
foo(@bar);
foo(CArray[DWORD]);  # <-- Use a type object to pass a NULL pointer
```

**Output**:

```
Got bar: 1
Got NULL pointer
```